# Shell script to check whether the entered file name is a hidden file or not in RadHat Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do i create a script to check for the file is hidden or not?

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
 
if [ -f "$FILE" ];
then
   echo "File $FILE is not hidden."
else
   echo "File $FILE is hidden" >&2
fi
```

but it is unable to do so. Please help me.

Comment: You could check this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/how-to-detect-if-a-file-is-hidden once, looks like same question could help you.

Comment: Just check if the first character of the filename is `.`

Comment: you can use command like if [[ $base == .* ]] to check if the filename starts with . or not.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the filename begins with `.`:

```
file=$1
base=$(basename "$file")

if [[ $base == .* ]]
then echo "File $file is hidden"
else echo "File $file is not hidden"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You essentially have to check if filename starts with . (period).

```
filename=$(basename -- "$FILE")
```

Then  you have to use pattern matching

```
if  [[ $filename == .* ]]
then
# do something
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The test command would be:

```
[[ "${file##*/}" == .* ]]
```

It's necessary to remove the path, to see if file name starts with `.`. Here I used prefix removal. It's the most efficient, but will choke if a file contains slashes (very unlikely, but be aware).

A full script should include a test that the given file actually exists:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

[[ -e "$file" ]] && { echo "File does not exist: $file" >&2; exit 1; }

if [[ "${file##*/}" == .* ]]; then
        echo "Hidden: $file"
else
        echo "Not hidden: $file"
fi
```

You could also list all hidden files in a directory:

```
find "$dir" -name .\*
```

Or all not hidden files:

```
find "$dir" -name '[^.]*'
```

Depending on the task, it's probably better to use a list of hidden or not hidden files, to work on.

Also, by default, `ls` does not list hidden files. Unless you use `-a`.